# Why using unlink() won't delete the folder specified?

Tags: r, directory

I've created a folder using `dir.create` function but when I tried to delete it  using `unlink` function I didn't have success.How can I overcome this issue?
Here is my toy code:

```
NewFolder<-dir.create("C://TestFolder")
unlink(NewFolder, recursive = T)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `NewFolder` doesn't have any path information (it returns `TRUE`).

```
NewFolder <- "C:/TestFolder"
dir.create(NewFolder)
unlink(NewFolder, recursive = T)
```